# Format date to ISO 8601 using Hibernate JPQL

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, grails-orm, jpql

Using JPQL I have to group my date time without time information, already have tried something like this:

```
SELECT YEAR(date)||'-'||MONTH(date)||'-'||DAY(date), SUM(duration) FROM Entity GROUP BY YEAR(date)||'-'||MONTH(date)||'-'||DAY(date) ORDER BY 1
```

But in this case "DAY(date)" will return day with one digit, e.g. "2019-1-1", and that does't match with ISO 8610 "2019-01-01"

Using: **Hibernate Core {5.3.12.Final}**

Any smart ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

JPQL does not contain date formatting. 
Why don't you get the date object from JPQL and format it in Java?

Alternatively, if you use JPA version 2.1 you can use native SQL functions inside JPQL

```
SELECT FUNCTION('date_format', date, '%Y-%m-%d'), SUM(duration) FROM Entity GROUP BY YEAR(date)||'-'||MONTH(date)||'-'||DAY(date) ORDER BY 1
```

Or you can use Native Query and use SQL date formatting.

Comment: Yeah... I will probably do in Java, but in mean while I was looking for some better solution, thanks for the SQL alternative!

Answer (score 0):

For format the date fields, function is available in JPQL. My JPA version is 1.11.9. Sample working group by day query:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT count(ac) as count, function('date_format', max(ac.subscriptionStartDate), '%Y, %m, %d') as date FROM MyTable ac " +
        "WHERE ac.subscriptionStartDate BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate GROUP BY function('date_format', ac.subscriptionStartDate, '%Y, %m, %d')")
public List<Map<String,Object>> findRegisteredCustomersHistory(@Param("startDate") Date startDate, @Param("endDate") Date endDate);
```

The result of the query is the list that records the number of records grouped by days in formatted form.

Sample result rows:

```
count: 3, date: 2019, 09, 10
count: 1, date: 2019, 09, 11
```

Simple JPQL function query:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT function('date_format', s.date, '%Y, %m, %d') as date from Table s;")
```